# How can I change the proxy settings for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

How can I change the proxy settings for Google Chrome?

Comment: duplication? http://superuser.com/questions/106467/chrome-not-saving-proxy-username-password

Comment: Be aware that Chrome uses the same proxy settings as the rest of your computer. Changing your proxy settings "in Chrome" actually pulls up your Mac/Windows system proxy information, and any changes you make will affect other browsers and any other applications that connect to the internet. [There aren't any "Chrome specific" proxy settings.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96815?hl=en)

Comment: @HartleyBrody, Odd, FF has its own proxy. So when will Chrome has its own settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Google's help docs](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96815) show how to do this:

1. Click the wrench menu tools menu.

   [image: wrench icon]
2. Select Options.
3. Click the Under the Hood tab.
4. In the 'Network' section, click the Change proxy settings button. This will open the 'Internet Properties' dialog box in Windows where you can adjust your network settings. See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135982) for more details.

Comment: These are Internet Explorer settings, which means Google chrome does not use its own proxy settings, right?

Comment: Yep. Changing these settings affects Google Chrome as well as Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 6):

[Use Proxy Switchy!](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj)

It lets you store profiles for different proxy settings and switching is done really easy.

[image]

Comment: It's called [Proxy SwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm) now

Comment: How does it work? Is it localized to Chrome or is it editing the system's proxy settings?

Comment: No idea @Pacerier, I no longer use the extension

Answer (score 4):

> When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the
>   system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not
>   supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man
>   google-chrome for more information on flags and environment variables.

Running the latest Chrome on Xubuntu & it's possible to start it with Terminal, so that it will use a localhost proxy called Privoxy:

google-chrome --proxy-server="https=127.0.0.1:8118;http=127.0.01:8118"

However, this doesn't stick and it isn't simple to edit the menus to use it. I'm looking for a way to insert the proxy information in .config/google-chrome but so far it's just wishful thinking.

Comment: Is the `--proxy-server` flag documented or undocumented?

Answer (score 2):

Click the wrench at the top, select options.

On the Under the Hood tab, scroll down to 'Change Proxy Settings'

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about how to configure proxy server on google chrome, well there are 3 ways:

1. Using system proxy setting, that also mean will change the whole system proxy
2. Using Extension like SwitchySharp / Proxy Switchy
3. by using Google Chrome Command Line Switches

You can find all the step-by-step tutorial for all 3 ways here http://howto.software-mirrors.com/2013/09/how-to-use-proxy-server-on-google-chrome.html

If you are looking for Proxy server IP and Port, I usually use this website http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list
change the options according to what you need, and it will find proxy servers that always up to date.

Answer (score 0):

For bypassing the system proxy or to use a specific proxy in Chrome based browsers, I posted an answer on this topic:
[Chrome: Do not use system-wide proxy settings](https://superuser.com/questions/419954/chrome-do-not-use-system-wide-proxy-settings/)

Answer (score -1):

The [Proxy SwitchOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif) extension does what Proxy SwitchySharp is supposed to do except it actually installs as of Chrome 56 (because this is not NPAPI type).