# Google chrome proxy authentication dialogue timeout

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, authentication

I am on a network that uses LDAP proxy for authentication based on a username and password.

Whenever I start Google Chrome, it pops up with a proxy authentication dialogue, but the dialogue disappears automatically after variable amount of time (sometimes it stays for 5 seconds some times less than 1 second).  I have found the same issue with Chromium also.

Is there any configuration I can set to control this timeout, or say, auto-authenticate with my authentication details from the shell or DE (Gnome3 on Arch)?

Comment: Which version are you using? I use chrome in Ubuntu and don't face any such problem

Comment: I am using chrome dev channel 22.0 on Arch

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of dialog box and which Operating system you are using

Comment: I am using arch linux. The authentication dialogue looks exactly same as the normal one, just that it auto goes off in a short time.

Comment: In FF there is a about:config setting "signon.autologin.proxy" that takes up boolean values. Is there any such thing for chrome?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. I would love if anyone knew of a resolution. Just started to today for some reason. I'm on Windows however.

Answer (score 3):

One of your Chrome extensions is causing this.

Go to `chrome://extensions/` and disable each extension until the problem goes away.

For me, the cause was [DataJog](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/datajog/jdjbfenehinjhopphkdodhkamhikjmij) but it could be any of them for you.

Comment: I just wanted to note that for me the cause was because of Adblock for youtube. Disabling that made the problem go away for me. I was using version 4.2.0 when I saw problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue before which I resolved using by passing in the proxy parameters in the shortcut.

get the properties of the shortcut your using to start chrome and append this to the end

```
--proxy-server=SERVER:PORT
```

Pays to use the IP rather than a hostname, seems to like it better.

If you're still getting the prompt then you might need to pass in your username and password, but that would be a last resort.

```
--proxy-user-and-password=USERNAME:PASSWORD
```

Hope that helps¬

Answer (score 0):

[I cannot comment to your question, due to reputation although I think this should go into a comment as it is not my own answer]

From this [previous SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/106467/why-is-google-chrome-not-saving-proxy-username-password), the only workaround I found for this issue was the anwser given by [Amos](https://superuser.com/users/114042/amos-batista): auto-fill username/password from Chrome when the pop up arises, https://superuser.com/a/379382/54151.

I am also using Gnome (2 for what matters), and set automatic authentication with my credentials in the Proxy settings and it did not work. Although, it used to worked with no problem in my previous version of Google Chrome (current one is Version 23.0.1271.22 beta).

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by chrome extensions. As Marc-Olivier Titeux suggested try removing extension. For me it was caused by Video Downloader plus extesnison.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue and found a couple of not-so-easy workarounds.

1. Save your proxy login and password in [chrome://settings/passwords](https://chrome://settings/passwords).
2. Open your computer's proxy settings manually or via [chrome://settings/?search=proxy](https://chrome://settings/?search=proxy) and enter your proxy login and password.

**Please go to Google Chrome Help and upvote the related posts** as this *may* be a relatively easy fix for Chrome developers:

- [Google chrome but a pop up appears asking me to login to a proxy](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/18255542?hl=en)
- [Proxy login pops-up and disappears before I ...](https://support.google.com/chrome/search?q=Proxy%20login%20pop-up%20disappears#:%7E:text=Proxy%20login%20pops%2Dup%20and%20disappears%20before%20I%20...)