# Chrome: Do not use system-wide proxy settings

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy

Is it possible to configure the proxy for chrome separately, i.e. without using the global windows proxy configuration?

I remember there were some discussions about adding a commandline switch for it to allow extensions to handle setting the proxy, but a quick look at the chrome extension list just gave me tons of "use proxy xyz for site xxx" addons but nothing simple to just give me an UI to configure the proxy only for Chrome.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No such simple UI exists AFAIK.

You can use proxy profiles with [Proxy SwitchyOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif?hl=en), or define it command line using [--proxy-server parameter](http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html).

Comment: Example: chrome.exe --proxy-server=myproxy:8080

Comment: "--proxy-server" and "--no-proxy-server" parameters seem not to work in Chrome. Maybe they work only in Chromium?

Comment: @HonzaZidek working fine for me (just tested, functionality is still here), and it has been working for a lot of people for a long time. Using Chrome 51, never used Chromium.

Comment: Well, what I want to achieve is NO PROXY. I tried `--no-proxy-server` and this seems completely ignored by my Chrome (tried with versions 50, 51 and 52beta). Can I get the effective result of NO PROXY using `--proxy-server=something`?

Comment: probably not. Also: I've been referring to `--proxy-server`, there is no `--no-proxy-server` parameter listed anywhere that I can see. Where did you find that?

Comment: Ok, it is mentioned [here](https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc). That might be Chromium only, don't know.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Bit of a necropost here, but I just ran into this problem.  `--proxy-server` only works on a brand new instance.  If Chrome is already running, you will just attach to it and use it's settings.  To be sure of a new context, create a temporary directory and tell chrome to use it for user data: `--user-data-dir="C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\<random_guid>" `

Answer (score 2):

I see it's an old topic, but as, in my opinion, the most accurate solution was not yet given, I decided to add it now.

To bypass system wide proxy setting for Chrome type browsers, use or take example on Chrome policies (`chrome://policy/`) as described here :
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9131254?hl=en

It consists in using Group Policy Management Editor, in which you previously add the Chrome related (ADM/ADMX) policies, downloaded here:
https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip
[image]
[image]
Unfortunately, this works only for Google Chrome, and by the way it's noted deprecated (but it still works for me on Chromium 108.x)
You only have to look at the registry key where those policy setting are written. (Note!: I use here a Windows 7 32bit. Query/adjust to your Windows version as needed.)

For Google Chrome it's:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
```

for (Ungoogled) Chromium it's:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Chromium
```

So, basically you have just to make some tries copy/pasting those keys (for example Registry Workshop does it) obtained via the use of the group policy editor mentioned above, and open `chrome://policy/` and refresh/reload then open `chrome://settings/system` and refresh to see changes and of course try by loading a website...

Depending on the Chrome brand you use (Google, Ungoogled Chromium:which I use, Comodo or others) you have to figure out the right key to paste the value into.

For example,
IF YOU WANT TO **BYPASS SYSTEM PROXY SETTING** in Chrome, set (DWORD) "ProxyServerMode" to 0.
IF YOU WANT TO **USE A SPECIFIC PROXY** in Chrome, set "ProxyServerMode" to 2 and enter the url string including the port into (string) "ProxyServer" (as for example 127.0.0.1:8080).
[image]

Thats it.
You can find out more by playing around with it.